# BCP using xp_cmdshell to generate outputfile

Tags: sql-server, bcp, xp-cmdshell

I'm using the following to generate an output file for some xml content stored in an image data type:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'BCP "SELECT XML FROM MyDatabase.dbo.myTable WHERE id = 1 " queryout "C:\temp\exportdir\myfile.xml" -T -S XYZ\SQLEXPRESS'
```

But I get the following message: `Enter the file storage type of field XML [image]`

The file gets generated but it's empty?

Comment: It's ok I've managed to fix by adding switch -n